# Is there a project management system that exports one user's contribution (or task completed) as a csv file?

Tags: project-management, csv

I am leading an open source/volunteering project and I would like to encourage other volunteers to contribute as well. If the contributions can be exported to a csv file, then it may be possible to automate things like certificate generation that people can take pride in...

Answer (score 0):

The only program I could think of is Microsoft project desktop or one of the 2 versions of projects online. There's a thing called projects web app, in a separate online one called projects for the web. For the reporting feature projects for the web is 30 bucks per month. For users who don't need the reporting feature it's $10 per month for each user.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/project/compare-microsoft-project-management-software

disclosure: we are a Microsoft partner